# How to get system drive volume serial number

Tags: nsis

I am building a setup which requires to retrieve the disk volume of the drive on which the Operating system is installed. I have tried the following code:

```nsis
Function ShowDiskVolumeSerialNumber
  !define GetVolumeInformation "Kernel32::GetVolumeInformation(t,t,i,*i,*i,*i,t,i) i"
  System::Call '${GetVolumeInformation ("$0",,${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN},.r0,,,,${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})'
  IntFmt $0 "%08X" $0
  MessageBox MB_OK $0
FunctionEnd
```

I call the above function by specifying the desired drive:

```nsis
StrCpy $0 "C:\"
Call ShowDiskVolumeSerialNumber
```

The above gives the volume no of `c:\` drive. However if my OS is installed on `d:\` or `e:\` it will not work. I want a function which will automatically detect the drive on which the OS is installed and retrieve its volume no.

Secondly, the volume number retrieved is without a hyphen (e.g. `349620C1`). I need the volume serial number retrieved as `3496-20C1`.

Could someone please give a complete NSIS function when will do both the things i.e:

1. Automatically detect the drive on which the OS is installed and retrieve its serial no with a hyphen in between.

Answer (score 0):

To get the OS drive, `StrCpy $0 $windir 3` is probably enough (You did not specify if you wanted the [boot volume or the system volume](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314470), on most systems they are the same so $windir is a good starting point)

To edit the serial number:

```
StrCpy $0 $serial 4
StrCpy $serial $serial "" 4
StrCpy $serial "$0-$serial"
```